# Echo to a specific URL instead of text message not working

Tags: php, echo

I can't get to send visitors to the Thank you page using ECHO method. 
Please help!

```
<?php
    } 
else                

    {
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];

    if (($name=="")||($email==""))
        {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">THE FORM</a> again.";
        }
    else{        
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject="Subscription Request from Website";
        mail("test@test.com", $subject, $message, $from);

       echo "Location: thankyou-subscription.php";
        }
    }  
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` does not redirect unless it outputs some JavaScript code or HTML Meta Refresh. If you have to redirect via only PHP, use `header` and also make sure nothing is sent to browser before that `header`, not even a blank line

```
echo "Location: thankyou-subscription.php";
```

should be

```
header("Location: thankyou-subscription.php");
```

**Edit**

Since you mentioned you cannot avoid echo before redirect, you can use JavaScript because PHP redirect won't work after output. You can do

```
echo "<script>location.href='thankyou-subscription.php';</script>";
```

Comment: I replaced echo with  header("Location: thankyou-subscription.php"); but it remains on the same page still.

Comment: Then you are sending any output to browser before that. Even a white space from HTML will cause header to fail. Make sure there is no echo no html being sent to browser before your Header call

Comment: I have to echo once before for the required fields. <?php
    } 
else                
    {
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
  
    if (($name=="")||($email==""))
        {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">THE FORM</a> again.";
        }
    else{        
        $from="From: $name <$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject="Subscription Request from Website";
        mail("itest@test.com", $subject, $message, $from);
        header("Location: http://test.com/thankyou-subscription.php");       
        }
    }  
?>

Comment: Ok then you can use a javascript redirect, one min leme update my answer

Comment: You are a GENIUS. The mix of ECHO and SCRIPT worked like a charm. Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Please use the [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to redirect users.

Example:

```
header("Location: thankyou-subscription.php");
```

You should also [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) after `echo "All fields are ..."`.

Comment: Good answer, also make sure no output is sent before the header function, otherwise it will fail with an ugly warning.

Answer (score 1):

Don't echo, instead do this:

```
header("Location: thankyou-subscription.php)";
```